# JQuery - How to remove 'disable' from all form inputs on page load

Tags: jquery, forms, addclass, document-ready, disabled-input

I am loading a page with all of the inputs & selects in a form starting as disabled. I have scripts to "edit" that work perfectly when clicking a button, but I'm trying to do the same thing on the page load when the record is "new". Whether or not the WHY makes sense, here's the code:

```
<?php  if($_GET['new'] == "yes"){  ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#edit,#addnotes,#addtasks').addClass('hidden');
    var form = $(this).closest('form').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    var form = $(this).closest('form').find('select').prop('disabled', false);
    form.children('input').removeAttr("disabled");
});
</script>
<?php }  ?>
```

The `$('#save').removeClass('hidden');` works just fine, as does the next line, but the form part is not working. Here is what DOES work when clicking the Edit button on my page:

```
$('#edit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    var form = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('select').prop('disabled', false);
    form.children('input').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#save,#cancel').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#edit,#addnotes,#addtasks').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Why not have them `disabled` in the HTML

Comment: @tymeJV Possibly because there are a fair number of images/etc to load, and he wants them to be disabled until the full page is loaded.

Comment: The fields are all dynamically generated from a db most of the time and I don't want them editable until clicking "Edit". There are some cases where we create a new record and can't start with them disabled. I could make a secondary page for New, but that's boring and doesn't involve cool JQuery! (it's also cumbersome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DOM ready, `this` is not the same thing as in the `click` event. Since your click event is bind on `#edit`, you could (to have exactly the same) replace every `this` by `'#edit'` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#save').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#edit,#addnotes,#addtasks').addClass('hidden');
    var form = $('#edit').closest('form').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    var form = $('#edit').closest('form').find('select').prop('disabled', false);
    form.children('input').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Of course - I knew it was something easy that I was missing. I just did `$('#webform')` (the name of the form, of course) and it worked.